# AWS EKS - Unable to read logs for any container from cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubectl, amazon-eks

I have deployed an AWS EKS Cluster, and I was able to read logs from cli without any issues. After deploying an application, I started getting this error from the CLI.

while running the logs command, I was not getting any output. but after waiting for a while . I started getting this error:

logs command : kubectl logs "appname" -n "namespace"

error: Error from server: Get [https://x.x.x.x:10250/containerLogs/"namespace"/"appname"](https://x.x.x.x:10250/containerLogs/%22namespace%22/%22appname%22): dial tcp x.x.x.x:10250: i/o timeout

Comment: Is the node where your "appname" runs healthy?

Answer (score 1):

after editing the security group for the server (cli) which is running the EKS cluster, adding the specific PORTs . it started working .